# How to count items of 2D array?

Tags: c++, multidimensional-array

I want to count the number of items in 2D array.

**For example**

```
char arr[][10] = {"Hello", "I'm", "Jack"};
```

The previous array has 3 rows (`Hello`, `I'm`, `Jack`) and 10 column like (`Hello` is 5 from 10 length).

Everyone know that when we want to get count of array with a single dimension, we do the following.

```
int size = (sizeof(arr) / sizeof(char));
```

But now we need a way to know, how many rows in the array, alone ?
and another way to know, how many columns in the array also, alone ?

Comment: *The previous array has 3 rows and 10 column* -- no it doesn't I don't know where you get the 10 from, but that is wrong.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The more general form is

```
int n_rows = sizeof(arr)/sizeof(arr[0]);
int n_cols = sizeof(arr[0])/sizeof(arr[0][0]);
```

Answer (score 8):

You can do it like this.

```
template<typename T, size_t M, size_t N>
size_t array_rows(const T (&arr)[M][N]) {
    return M;
}

template<typename T, size_t M, size_t N>
size_t array_columns(const T (&arr)[M][N]) {
    return N;
}
```

C++ supports another way of getting size called [`std::extent`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/extent)